# Ubuntu sdk filedialog

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, qml

I have tried to make a video playback application and this is the code I have got so far:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0
Video {
    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        title: "Please choose a file(.mp4)"



        Component.onCompleted: visible = true
    }
    id: video
    width : units.gu(120)
    height : units.gu(90)
    source : fileDialog.fileUrl
    MouseArea {
        Text
        {
            text : "click to play,space for stop,left and right to seek position in video"
        }
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            video.play()
        }
    }
    focus: true
    Keys.onSpacePressed: video.playbackState == MediaPlayer.PlayingState ? video.pause() : video.play()
    Keys.onLeftPressed: video.seek(video.position - 5000)
    Keys.onRightPressed: video.seek(video.position + 5000)
}
```

The code runs perfectly fine from my IDE,however when I install it on my Ubuntu 15.04 with unity 8 on my laptop the app just crashes.
I am guessing QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0 might not be part of the platform?Then how do I package it in my .click?Or is there an alternative that is part of the platform?

Answer (score 0):

The truth is that the API does not provide support for this. Because the API implements sandboxing trough the content hub. My application would have to go trough the sandbox.